# Expand div from right to left? HTML - CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

as you can see in the picture, next to each profile pic, theres a yellow container that has a text, if the text is short, it will stay in the right position, but if the text is too large, it wil increase, i want it increase from right to left, no left to right, heres the code:

```
<div className = "d-flex" style = {{overflow: "hidden", marginBottom: "15px"}}>
   <div style = {{overflow: "hidden"}}>
      <div className = "chat_name" style = {{left: "0", textAlign: "left", marginTop: "0"}}>
        <p>hola kdfdofhsdfohsofhsdohsfoho</p> 
      </div>
   </div>
   <div className = "image_wrap_mini_chat">
      <img src = {Profile_pic}/>
   </div>
</div>
```

heres the style of chat_name:

```
.chat_name {
    background-color: yellow; 
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -60px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of something similar you are trying to obtain:

```css
.chat__user-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.chat__user-image {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.char__user-name {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat__user-container">
   <img class="chat__user-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200"/>
   <p class="chat__user-name">John Doe</p> 
</div>

<div class="chat__user-container">
   <img class="chat__user-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200"/>
   <p class="chat__user-name">John Doe Longer</p> 
</div>
```

There is no need to over complicate your HTML structure.